# Mock out clientWidth of an element created during execution

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a typescript function:

renderDOM.ts

```
export function renderShadowDOMButton(
    containerElement: HTMLElement,
    buttonId: string,
): void {
    let shadow = containerElement.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
    const microtextContent =
        wrapper.clientWidth < 150
            ? doSomethingForLessWidth()
            : doSomethingForMoreWidth();
    let container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(microtextContent);
}
```

renderDOM.test.ts

```
it('should call function for more width', () => {
    let renderEl = document.createElement('div');

    webComponentHelper.renderShadowDOMButton(renderEl, 'someButtonId');
   expect(doSomethingForMoreWidth).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The above test always fails since wrapper.clientWidth is 0. I wanted to understand if I can mock out the clientWidth of wrapper.
I tried the solutions mentioned here but I can set the clientWidth for containerElement and not for wrapper.

- [Mocking clientHeight and scrollHeight in React + Enzyme for test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823616/mocking-clientheight-and-scrollheight-in-react-enzyme-for-test)
- [How to set or mock element scrollHeight and element clientHeight in testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443320/how-to-set-or-mock-element-scrollheight-and-element-clientheight-in-testing)